# SWIG argument error when using "using std::vector" in python

Tags: python, c++, c++11, vector, swig

This is very related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491921/how-to-use-a-python-list-to-assign-a-stdvector-in-c-using-swig) question

Regardless of whether or not this is coding practice, I have come across code that looks like this

**test.hh**

```
#include <vector>                                                                                   
using std::vector;                                                             

class Test 
{                                                                     
    public:                                                                      
        vector<double> data;                                                     
};
```

I am trying to swig this using swig3.0 using the following interface file

**test.i**

```
%module test_swig                                                                

%include "std_vector.i"                                                          

namespace std {                                                                  
    %template(VectorDouble) vector<double>;                                      
};                                                                               

%{                                                                               
    #include "test.hh"                                                               
%}                                                                               

%naturalvar Test::data;                                                                                 
%include "test.hh"
```

And the following test code

**test.py**

```
t = test.Test()                                                              
jprint(t)                                                                    
a      = [1, 2, 3]                                                                
t.data = a # fails
```

doing so gives me the following error

```
in method 'Test_data_set', argument 2 of type 'vector< double >'
```

This can be fixed by either changing the `using std::vector` in test.hh to `using namespace std` or by removing `using std::vector` and changing `vector<double>` to `std::vector<double>`.  This is not what I want.

The problem is that I was given this code as is.  I am not allowed to make changes, but I am supposed to still make everything available in python via SWIG.  What's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Putting using statements in header files is a no-no, and you're finding out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this looks like SWIG does not support the `using std::vector;` statement correctly. I think it's a SWIG bug. I can think of the following workarounds:

- Add `using namespace std;` to the SWIG interface file (this will only affect the way wrappers are created; the `using` statement will not enter C++ code)
- Add `#define vector std::vector` to the SWIG interface file (this will only work if `vector` is never used as `std::vector`)
- Copy the declarations from the header file to the SWIG interface file, and change `vector` to `std::vector`. This will cause SWIG to generate correct wrappers, and again will not affect the C++ library code.

Comment: (Or just not force `using` on everyone by having them at global scope inside header files).

Comment: I agree with Flexo, without a doubt.  That might be the best way to handle this, but unfortunately, that was not the question.  As far as m7thon's response, the first bullet seems to override the `using std::vector` in the h file.  Very nice!  The other options are iffy, but I'll count it as closed because of the first bullet.

Comment: The third point (copying and customizing the declarations) is in some sense the "correct" way to go and guaranteed to work. Using `%include "test.hh"` is really a shortcut for when the header file can be used as is. The first two points are hacks, but if they work... ;-)